# How do I avoid inserting duplicate data in PostgreSQL?

Tags: python, postgresql

How to avoid inserting duplicate data? I only want to insert data that does not already exist. I have written following queries but its not working properly. I'm using `PostgreSQL`.

```
title_exits = cursor.execute ("SELECT title,pageid FROM movie_movie WHERE title = %s AND pageid = %s;",(title,pageid))
    if title_exits == 0:
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO movie_movie (title,pageid,slug,language) values (%s,%s,%s,%s);",(title,pageid,slug,id))
    db.commit()
```

Update: I tried `result = cursor.fetchone ("SELECT count(*) FROM movie_movie WHERE title = %s AND pageid = %s;",(title,pageid))`. But I'm getting error message. `TypeError: fetchone() takes not arugments (2 given).`

Comment: That `cursor.execute` is from psycopg2?

Comment: Have you looked at this question and decision? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511679/python-number-of-rows-affected-by-cursor-executeselect)

Comment: @madth3 yes `cursor = db.cursor()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer related to your update:

You should use "%" symbol instead comma:

```
result = cursor.fetchone ("SELECT count(*) FROM movie_movie WHERE title = %s AND pageid = %s;" % (title,pageid))
```

**update**

as @no_freedom said in comments, think better approach would be

```
result = cursor.fetchone ("SELECT count(*) FROM movie_movie WHERE title = :1 AND pageid = :2", [title,pageid])
```

But i'm not sure, just try it.

Comment: @no_freedom i think you're right, i'm going to update my answer.

Comment: I tried. But getting same error message. `TypeError: fetchone() takes not arugments (2 given)`

Comment: but you've used wrong brackets, you've used these "()". did you try with such ones "[]"?

Answer (score 0):

Try to define title field as unique(must define as varchar(constant_length)). Then try insert title into database if title exists, db return error else will insert

Comment: its already unique. But I don't want show error on terminal. If `found then skip`.

Comment: you can handle an exception in case you have duplicate record on table, and just pass.

Comment: Maybe you could check what returns in title_exists var from execute function. Then try to take count from your SQL.

Comment: And I noticed you did not check only title you also check pageid. So not only given title checked also pageid checked in your SQL(title-pageid must same as DB according to your SQL) and maybe title exists but pageid different from exist pageid. May it be cause of not working properly?

Answer (score 0):

As I suspected (and @tony points out) cursor.execute does not return the number of rows. It always return `None`.